# How to change the series icon shape in Kendo UI linechart?Can I use custom icon?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I know the default icon is "circle",now I want to change the icon shape.The total icon shape are only "circle", "square", "triangle", "cross".Can Iuse custome icon?I use these codes in the databound event,but it seems not work.

```
var colorArr = new Array("#FF0000", "#FF8C00", "#006400", "#40E0D0", "#800080");
var iconShapeArr = newArray("circle", "square", "triangle", "cross");
function onDataBound(e) {
 var chart = e.sender;
 var series = chart.options.series;
 for(var index = 0; index <= series.length - 1; index++) {
     chart.options.series[index].color = colorArr[index];
     chart.options.series[index].markers.background = colorArr[index];
    // chart.options.series[index].notes.icon.shape = "square";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know,it can not be custom.You can change the type like these:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
var colorArr = ["#FF0000", "#FF8C00", "#006400", "#40E0D0", "#800080"];
var iconShapeArr = ["triangle", "square", "triangle", "cross"];
var chart = e.sender;
var series = chart.options.series;
for(var index = 0; index <= series.length - 1; index++) {
   chart.options.series[index].color = colorArr[index];
   chart.options.series[index].markers.background = colorArr[index];
   chart.options.series[index].markers.type = iconShapeArr[index];
  }
}
```